# Kotlin: Can JSONObject parse custom object?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am trying to store Map object into android shared preferences for which below is the code:

```
private fun setMap(context: Context, key: String, value: Map<String, Any>) {
        val editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
        val jsonObject = JSONObject(value)
        val jsonString = jsonObject.toString()
        editor.putString(key, jsonString)
        editor.apply()
}
```

If my Map is of type `Map<String, String> or Map<"test","123">` then the above code works just fine and jsonObject on line 2 is `{"test", "123"}`.

However if my Map contains any custom object such as `Map<String, CustomObject> i.e. Map<"test", CustomObject()>`, then I jsonObject on line 2 is `{"test", null}`.

Can JSONObject parse custom object?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a json (i.e. converting your object to json and converting json to your object) using Gson library or this library: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the implementation of `JSONObject` in this case.

The documentation for the parameter of the `JSONObject(Map)` constructor states

```
 * @param copyFrom a map whose keys are of type {@link String} and whose
 *     values are of supported types.
```

But to find what constitutes a valid value, you have to look at `wrap(entry.getValue())` which is called within the constructor. The documentation for `wrap` states:

```
/**
 * Wraps the given object if necessary.
 *
 * <p>If the object is null or , returns {@link #NULL}.
 * If the object is a {@code JSONArray} or {@code JSONObject}, no wrapping is necessary.
 * If the object is {@code NULL}, no wrapping is necessary.
 * If the object is an array or {@code Collection}, returns an equivalent {@code JSONArray}.
 * If the object is a {@code Map}, returns an equivalent {@code JSONObject}.
 * If the object is a primitive wrapper type or {@code String}, returns the object.
 * Otherwise if the object is from a {@code java} package, returns the result of {@code toString}.
 * If wrapping fails, returns null.
 */
```

In your case, I'm guessing your map value doesn't meet any of the criteria for returning a non-null value, which I would expect for a non `java.*` non `JSON*` object.

With that said, I would advise against storing complex objects and structures in `SharedPreferences` (it isn't optimal for that) and suggest using database. However, if you're set on this route, definitely look at the [Kotlin Serialization library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization).